# How to add a Array value to another array

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a random password Generator and want to add an array value to another array "pa" in order to make a single string password. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package project;
 import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.util.Random;
public class RandomPass {

public static void Randpass(){
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random();
String[] alphabet=  {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to RandomPassword Generator");
int c= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How long do you want the password"));
int nc =0-c;
int c2=c/2;
int nc2= 0-c2;
int ncm =(nc+1)/2;
String pa [];
if(c%2==0){
    for(int x=nc2;x<0;x++){
        int alphanum =rand.nextInt(26);
        pa.add(alphabet[alphanum]);
        int numNum =rand.nextInt(10);
        pa.add(numNum);
    }


}else{
    for(int x=ncm;x<0;x++){
        int alphanum =rand.nextInt(26);
        int numNum =rand.nextInt(10);

    }
}

}
}
```

Comment: Have you looked up the JavaDoc for `Collections` and or `Arrays`?

Comment: You might want to use an `ArrayList`. Arrays have a fixed size and work with indexes.

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`. Also, which version of Java is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Hello {
private static final String CHAR_LIST = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
private static final int RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH = 10;
    public String generateRandomString(){

        StringBuffer randStr = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH; i++){
            int number = getRandomNumber();
            char ch = CHAR_LIST.charAt(number);
            randStr.append(ch);
        }
        return randStr.toString();
    }


    private int getRandomNumber() {
        int randomInt = 0;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(CHAR_LIST.length());
        if (randomInt - 1 == -1) {
            return randomInt;
        } else {
            return randomInt - 1;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand =  new Random();
        Hello msr = new Hello();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(true)
        {
            list.add(msr.generateRandomString());
            //System.out.println("happy birthday smash from "+msr.generateRandomString());
        }
    }

}
```

I did for my birthday i made some modifications for it hope my code works.Happy coding

Comment: watch iam using infinite loop here loop according to your feasible set